# How to fetch the data of multiple table with one query using php and mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I really got stuck at the point whenI wanted to show data from multiple table i.e., in my case products & categories table. I have two table pic shown in below

I have following php code to show the data

```
 <div class="row">
 <?php
 require_once("connection.php");
 $query = "SELECT * FROM categories, products where cat_type = 'import' AND product_cat = cat_name";
 $result=$conn->query($query);
 while($row=$result->fetch_array()){
 ?>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
 <h5><?php echo $row['cat_name'];?></h5>
 <ul>
 <li><a href="category.php"><?php echo $row['product_title'];?></a>
 </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <?php } ?>
 </div>
```

I am getting output like this

[image: two category title for same cat]

Expected output 
[image: I want my out to be like this]

Comment: This question seems unresolved.  Can you provide the database table structure for `categories` and `products`?  Then we can easily help you to refine the query.  ...which might possibly include specific columns in the SELECT portion, all-uppercase keywords and table aliases throughout.

Answer (score 1):

**Query Like below**

```
 <?php
  $query = SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN table2 ON categories.id=table2.id where categories.cat_type = 'import' AND categories.product_cat = cat_name";
 ?>
```

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN products ON categories.cat_type=products .product_cat where categories.cat_type = 'import' AND categories.product_cat = cat_name"; its not working .. what am i doing wrong

Comment: have you cat_type column in categories table & also have product_cat in product table? have you category item in product.product_cat? the providing code is ok in my seance, so you check your database, and table relation again.

Comment: And "categories.cat_type=products .product_cat" don't space here "products(you write a space here).product_cat"

Answer (score -1):

Joins connect databases from the same host

`<?php $query = SELECT * FROM categories LEFT JOIN table2 ON categories.id=table2.id where categories.cat_type = 'import' AND categories.product_cat = cat_name"; ?>`

The code above is working fine.
**What is the error you have?**

Another thing:
**Never use** 
`while($row=$result->fetch_array()) {
 ?>`
 `<div>
HTML Code here 
 </div>
 <?php } ?>`

**Instead of 

{ 

Some HTML 

}** 
use echo and output your div in there.
Somerhing like 
`echo "<div class='col-md-3'>".$row['cat_name']."</div>"`

Comment: I am having the error in displaying the sub categories everything i add new sub category ... its is displayed with heading each time. I dont want multiple heading of same category rather the sub category should come within the main category as in pic